# ES6 import of a module runs non-exporeted function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, module, export

I have two files:a.js and b.js
I import a into b. 
I include b.js in the index.html

Why does test2 function run, even though I have only exported `test` function and not `test2`.
https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-sun-rrmnx?file=/src/a.js

//a.js

```
function test(){
  alert("Test")
}
function test2(){
  alert("test2")
}
test2();

export {test}
```

//b.js

```
import { test } from './a.js';
test()
```

Comment: Because you explicitly run it as part of defining that module? Why did you think it *wouldn't*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe but I am only importing `test` into module `b`. Shouldn't the rest of module `a` be inaccessible/un-executable from within module `b`?

Comment: It's *not* accessible from within module b, but that doesn't mean it never runs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have the same problem. How can I stop code outside a function from running?

Comment: @RedGuy11 delete it? Comment it out?

Comment: @jonrsharpe but I still want it to run when I call the file directly

Comment: @RedGuy11 then split it into *two* files, one you can import from and one that imports-and-runs.